# Android Bot Application using AIML

Tags: android, artificial-intelligence, bots, aiml

I am developing an Android Bot application which will take input from the user, check for a matching string in the AIML file and give corresponding output.

I know Android programming and also I have AIML files ready. The only problem I am facing is to fetch the output from the AIML files.

I have gone through some answers but I could not figure out a solution. I would be happy if you could explain it in detail.

I am using Android Studio for the development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@harivigneshjayapalan/android-baking-a-simple-chatbot-in-30-minutes-aiml-ff43c3269025#.5nhy0najt) to help me get started with my basic application that accepts my input, scans for the `AIML` files, and gives corresponding response.

The only issue with this tutorial is that it will just accept your input, scan the `AIML` file and search for matching text in the `<pattern>` tag and respond with whatever is present in the corresponding `<template>` tag.

If you have `<oob>` tags in your `AIML` files which perform special tasks like opening applications, searching on internet etc., you will have to write your own code which will do following tasks:

1. Scan the bot's response for presence of `<oob>` tag.
2. Remove the `<oob>` tag and contents between `<oob>` and `<\oob>` tags.
3. Perform whatever task is mentioned in those tags.